# What's the meaning of `netstat -i` flags

Tags: netstat, flags

When I run `netstat -i` in Linux, I get outputs like:

```
Kernel Interface table
Iface   MTU Met   RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
eth0       1500 0         0      0      0 0           236      0      0      0 BMPRU
eth1       1500 0       789      0      0 0           269      0      0      0 BMRU
lo        16436 0      3715      0      0 0          3715      0      0      0 LRU
```

I'm wondering what are those `Flg` mean? Could someone give me an exhausted list of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`netstat` is open-source, you can look-up these values in its source code. The program is built from the [`net-tools`](http://net-tools.sourceforge.net/) package. From `lib/interface.c` `ife_print_short` (via `ifconfig.c`):

```
    if (ptr->flags == 0)
        printf(_("[NO FLAGS]"));
    if (ptr->flags & IFF_ALLMULTI)
        printf("A");
    if (ptr->flags & IFF_BROADCAST)
        printf("B");
    if (ptr->flags & IFF_DEBUG)
        printf("D");
    if (ptr->flags & IFF_LOOPBACK)
        printf("L");
    if (ptr->flags & IFF_MULTICAST)
        printf("M");
#ifdef HAVE_DYNAMIC
    if (ptr->flags & IFF_DYNAMIC)
        printf("d");
#endif
    if (ptr->flags & IFF_PROMISC)
        printf("P");
    if (ptr->flags & IFF_NOTRAILERS)
        printf("N");
    if (ptr->flags & IFF_NOARP)
        printf("O");
    if (ptr->flags & IFF_POINTOPOINT)
        printf("P");
    if (ptr->flags & IFF_SLAVE)
        printf("s");
    if (ptr->flags & IFF_MASTER)
        printf("m");
    if (ptr->flags & IFF_RUNNING)
        printf("R");
    if (ptr->flags & IFF_UP)
        printf("U");
```